# img src path will not update on vite build

Tags: html, build, bundler, vite

I'm trying to build a multi-page application with Vite. however, when I run a `vite build` script, it builds out my app in dist, but does not update my html's image source attribute. This is what one line of my html file looks like, and it remains the same in the build output (in dist folder).

```
<img src="../../assets/ac.svg"><>
```

I see that my ac.svg is in there since it's been rehashed and moved in `dist>assets`:

[image]

But my path never updates:

[image]

My other paths update normally to the new hashed asset:

[image]

I've tried changing my assets folder to be named 'public' but the path still does not update in my html files.

Another thing that doesn't change its URL is the favicon (from dist build html file):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```